# 3D world Coordinate estimation using stereo camera

Tags: opencv, 3d, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping, pose-estimation

I have a stack of know object. My problem is to find the World Coordinates(X,Y,Z) of the object using the stereo pair. 
I have done the following steps.

1. Stereo camera calibration, Got intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.
2. Un-Distort the image pair.
3. Stereo rectification to get the images in epipolar line.
4. I have segmented the object region from the image(I know the Object region in the image)

I know the formula z = (b*F) / (d*s) to calculate the depth.

Is there any function to find X,Y,Z in opencv.
My working distance is around 260mm, will i be able to get the depth accuracy of 1mm using triangulation method ?

I have also referred to these question which didnt answer my problem 
[Stereo vision: Depth estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956910/stereo-vision-depth-estimation)
[3D stereo, bad 3D coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577243/3d-stereo-bad-3d-coordinates)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html

Comment: @TimothyGroote Thanks for your response, I have the disparity map computed using SGBM. My problem is to find the 3D world coordinate using the Disparity map.

Comment: right, then you're after `reprojectImageTo3D`.
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d